# Find and replace value inside an array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects:

```
[
 {
    "enabled": true,
    "deviceID": "eI2K-6iUvVw:APA"
},
{
    "enabled": true,
    "deviceID": "e_Fhn7sWzXE:APA"
},
{
    "enabled": true,
    "deviceID": "e65K-6RRvVw:APA"
}]
```

A POST request is coming in with the deviceID of `eI2K-6iUvVw:APA`, all i want to do is to iterate the array, find the deviceID and change the `enabled` value to `false`.

How's that possible in javascript?

Comment: This is not proper JS data structure to start with.

Comment: The answer here is perfect. The "already has answers" above is to a 9 year old question and the answers aren't as good as this one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `Array#find`.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "enabled": true,
    "deviceID": "eI2K-6iUvVw:APA",
  },
  {
    "enabled": true,
    "deviceID": "e_Fhn7sWzXE:APA",
  },
  {
    "enabled": true,
    "deviceID": "e65K-6RRvVw:APA",
  },
];

const id = 'eI2K-6iUvVw:APA';

arr.find(v => v.deviceID === id).enabled = false;

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Any Idea, how we can update multiple key values at once, Like I need to update the deviceID along enabled

Comment: @LalitMohan Store found object in a variable and then change multiple properties: `const obj = arr.find(v => v.deviceID === id); obj.enabled = false; obj.deviceID = 'your ID';`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to copy the array with the new devices disabled:

```
const devices = [ /* ... */ ];

const newDevices = devices.reduce((ds, d) => {
  let newD = d;
  if (d.deviceID === 'eI2K-6iUvVw:APA') {
    newD = Object.assign({}, d, { enabled: false });
  }
  return ds.concat(newD);
}, []);
```

Comment: reduce is not really ideal for this type of operation since you're recreating the whole array with one property changed.

Comment: @James can you propose a better solution?