# JS : How to change the value of an object's property according to that object attribute

Tags: javascript, json, rest, typescript, ecmascript-6

i ve such a JSON data :

```
inputData = [
{ id : 179849, name : alex , lastname: sanchez},
{ id : 788539, name : Paul, lastname: bearer},
{ id : 282169, name : Jean, lastname: nobel},
...
{ id : 632785, name : Maria, lastname: parak}
]
```

i need to search some object according to its **id** value ***(for example: 788539 )***

and change the value of its **name** attribute 
 -> **name** becomes :  bruno

the data would become :

```
resultData= [
{ id : 179849, name : alex , lastname: sanchez},
{ id : 788539, name : bruno, lastname: bearer},  /* THIS ONE*/
{ id : 282169, name : Jean, lastname: nobel},
...
{ id : 632785, name : Maria, lastname: parak}
]
```

**What is the simpliest way to filter / map my data to do such a modification ?**

Comment: `resultData.find(o => o.id === 788539).name = "bruno"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace value inside an array of objects javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222724/find-and-replace-value-inside-an-array-of-objects-javascript)

Comment: You mentioned "filter/map", and it so happens that JS arrays have two handy methods by these names ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some alternatives, the one mentioned by [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) might need a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill):

```
// Mentioned by Felix Kling 
inputData.find(x => x.id === 788539)
  .name = 'Bruno'
```

You can also use the [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
for (let item of inputData) {
  if (item.id === 788539) {
    item.name = 'Bruno'
    break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
resultData= [
{ id : 179849, name : alex , lastname: sanchez},
{ id : 788539, name : bruno, lastname: bearer},  /* THIS ONE*/
{ id : 282169, name : Jean, lastname: nobel},
...
{ id : 632785, name : Maria, lastname: parak}
];

id = 788539;

resultData.forEach(ele=>{
    if(ele.id == id){
    ele.name = 'bruno'
    }
});

console.log(resultData);
```

Comment: FWIW, this will iterate the whole array even if the object was found. If the ID is not unique this is necessary, but if it is unique and this wastes time if the list is large.